# 'future' is not a registered tag library.

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am on working on my django 1.10 version. I have installed the library tastypie_swagger. When I am loading the url I am getting the below error.

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'future' is not a registered tag
 library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

How can I fix this ?. I am pretty new to django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `tastypie_swagger` that you are using does not support Django 1.9+ because it contains `{% load url from future %}` in the templates.

The problem has been fixed by [pull request 113](https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger/pull/113/files), but there hasn't been a release since then. You could try installing the master branch on GitHub, or switch to Django 1.8.

Comment: But i am using Django 1.10. Anyway I will try it out.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you are using Django 1.10. I should have said "switch to" Django 1.8.

Comment: :). Tried with the master branch . It worked . Thank you

Comment: i'd suggest pointing to a specific commit instead of the master branch, it might get updates that could potentially break something in the future